# How many people survived the Titanic?

Tags: 20th-century, nautical, disasters

How many people survived the Titanic?  Was it [706](http://www.titanicfacts.net/titanic-survivors.html), [706](http://www.titanicuniverse.com/how-many-people-survived-the-titanic-disaster/1253) or [705](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Titanic) or can we only say it was between [705 and 713](http://www.historyofthetitanic.org/titanic-survivors.html) ?  Where do these various number come from?

Comment: Not a full answer, but the best number based on research that I've seen is at [Encyclopedia Titanica](http://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic-statistics.html). They put the number at 712.

Comment: Encyclopedia Titanica, I love that.

Comment: The RMS Carparthia took 705 survivors to NY. Some of the discrepancies might be due to several initial survivors dying on the boats or on the way (especially those pulled out of the water).

Comment: @Semaphore If you look at the bottom of http://www.titanicinquiry.org/USInq/USReport/AmInqRep03.php#a8 it definitely says 706. Where does the number 705 come from?

Comment: @Lembik You do realise that the confusion exists *precisely because* these inquiries did not agree with each other?

Comment: @Semaphore http://www.titanicinquiry.org/BOTInq/BOTReport/botRepSaved.php says 711. Do you know where this figure of 705 comes from as it doesn't seem to come from either inquiry?  I can see that 6 people could easily have died after having been rescued of course.

Comment: @Lembik It's the number the RMS Carpathia reported taking to New York.

Comment: @Semaphore Thank you. Do you have a reference for that? A copy of an original document would be best of course.

Comment: @Lembik There is a list but I don't know where you might find it. Luckily, IIRC, you should be able to find that number in Captain Rostron's testimony to the Board of Trade. That's the British inquiry you linked to.

Comment: @Semaphore Actually the answer is entirely in http://www.titanicinquiry.org/BOTInq/BOTInq28Rostron02.php it seems. For example, "The Attorney-General:
There is some discrepancy in this; I will try to clear it up. There are 705 of which we have a list. There are six persons who were saved whose names did not appear in the list of the 705, but according to our knowledge now were actually saved by you, so that that would make 711 altogether were saved. That is not including either the three bodies found or the one which died shortly after."

Comment: @Lembik Yes, I know that's what the Board **thought** the number was (I did tell you about that document :p). The point though is that Captain Rostron **swore its 705**. Now, perhaps the board was right, but there shouldn't be such varied numbers in literature if it wasn't doubted. Though admittedly, in my first comment I should have said Carpathia *reportedly* took 705 to New York.